# How does `lookupIndex[row[lookupKey]] = row;` work?

Tags: javascript

I am reading [learnjsdata.com](http://learnjsdata.com/combine_data.html) and came across this unfamiliar JavaScript syntax. The syntax is as follows:

`lookupIndex[row[lookupKey]] = row;`

Anyone know what's happening here? I haven't seen syntax like this. Used in context:

**Data**

```
var articles = [{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "vacuum cleaner",
    "weight": 9.9,
    "price": 89.9,
    "brand_id": 2
}, {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "washing machine",
    "weight": 540,
    "price": 230,
    "brand_id": 1
}, {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "hair dryer",
    "weight": 1.2,
    "price": 24.99,
    "brand_id": 2
}, {
    "id": 4,
    "name": "super fast laptop",
    "weight": 400,
    "price": 899.9,
    "brand_id": 3
}];

var brands = [{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "SuperKitchen"
}, {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "HomeSweetHome"
}];
```

**Function & Invocation**

```
function join(lookupTable, mainTable, lookupKey, mainKey, select) {
    var l = lookupTable.length,
        m = mainTable.length,
        lookupIndex = [],
        output = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < l; i++) { // loop through l items
        var row = lookupTable[i];
        lookupIndex[row[lookupKey]] = row; // create an index for lookup table
    }
    for (var j = 0; j < m; j++) { // loop through m items
        var y = mainTable[j];
        var x = lookupIndex[y[mainKey]]; // get corresponding row from lookupTable
        output.push(select(y, x)); // select only the columns you need
    }
    return output;
};

var result = join(brands, articles, "id", "brand_id", function(article, brand) {
    return {
        id: article.id,
        name: article.name,
        weight: article.weight,
        price: article.price,
        brand: (brand !== undefined) ? brand.name : null
    };
});

console.log(result);
```

Appreciate any answers or pointers, thanks!

Comment: Thank you @freedomn-m. But, the console outputs are different. Using dot notation produces a `null` value for key `brand`.

Comment: @freedomn-m No, that is *not* the same thing - what you wrote is the same as `lookupIndex[row["lookupKey"]]` (with quotes).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think of it as two separate function calls:

```
var rowLookup = row[lookupKey];
lookupIndex[rowLookup] = row;
```

It's the same as doing it all in the same line:

```
lookupIndex[row[lookupKey]] = row;
```

Comment: The breakdown is correct, except you should call it *expressions* and not *function calls*.

Comment: So in your rephrasing `lookupIndex[rowLookup] = row;` assigns the result of `var row = lookupTable[i]; // brands[i]` and `var rowLookup = row[lookupKey];` to  `lookupIndex`?

Sort of feels like a job for `arr.push`? Thoughts, @PeterB?